# SharedPreferences loses data when application is destroyed

Tags: java, android, save

So I am trying to save data in sharePreferences in `onPaus()` method, I've tried same thing in `onCreate()` too, didn't work , here is a code :

```
public class Favorite extends Activity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
{
    private static final String PREFS_FILE = "com.example.stewiesh.eduguide.preferences1";
    private static final String KEY_FAVORITE = "Key_favorite";
    static   ArrayList<String> uniID = new ArrayList<String>();
   /** SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor; **/
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView list;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorite);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favoriteList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_layout);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
     //   preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     //   editor = preferences.edit();
    //    setData();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("i am out");
                SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                adapter.add(settings.getString(KEY_FAVORITE,"none of them is here bitch"));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });;
    }
/**
    public void setData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Page2.responses.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<uniID.size();j++)
            {
             if(Page2.responses[i].getPrograma().toString().equals(uniID.get(j)))
             {
                 editor.clear();
                 editor.putString(KEY_FAVORITE,Page2.responses[i].getFakulteti()+" -- "+Page2.responses[i].getUniversiteti()+" "+Page2.responses[i].getPrograma().toString());
             //    editor.commit();
               //  editor.apply();
             }
            }
        }
    }
**/
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
     //   preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        for (int i = 0; i < Page2.responses.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<uniID.size();j++)
            {
                if(Page2.responses[i].getPrograma().toString().equals(uniID.get(j)))
                {
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.putString(KEY_FAVORITE,Page2.responses[i].getFakulteti()+" -- "+Page2.responses[i].getUniversiteti()+" "+Page2.responses[i].getPrograma().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        }
       //editor.apply();
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {

    }
}
```

when I destroy app, than launch it , it gives me nothing, I can't get why it's not saving data,I've tried various things but...

Comment: Did you add log to block save data to sharepreference to sure that data has not problem ?

Comment: yeap, i tested that

Comment: Change commit to apply ?

Comment: First of all make sure that your editor.commit() statement is executed every iteration of the for loop. Also I am not able to understand that why are you clearing the editor at each and every iteration?

Comment: 1st i tried apply too and tried commit in every iteration too...

Comment: try after removing the editor.clear() . and check if the value is in the sharedpreferences after the editor.commit() is done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remove

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() {
});
```

this part from your code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("i am out");
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        adapter.add(settings.getString(KEY_FAVORITE,"none of them is here bitch"));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

because you are already running that part of your code in the UI thread, so adding runOnUiThread again is meaningless.

The reason why you weren't able to save anything is because you called
`editor.clear()` in the loop.

According to the Documentation:

> clear() - Mark in the editor to remove all values from the preferences.

All you need to do is just put and commit(), no need to call `editor.apply()`

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                for (int i = 0; i < Page2.responses.length; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<uniID.size();j++)
                    {
                        if(Page2.responses[i].getPrograma().toString().equals(uniID.get(j)))
                        {
             editor.putString(KEY_FAVORITE,Page2.responses[i].getFakulteti()+" -- "+Page2.responses[i].getUniversiteti()+" "+Page2.responses[i].getPrograma().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }

                editor.commit();
```

You don't need to kept on committing, only commit when you are done putting data.